# Issues on "Select" function to crawl relative drop-down menu in python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, select, web-crawler

I am using Select function in Selenium Python to manipulate the parent - child relation of drop-down menu on this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I). There are five drop-down menus on the first row. I completed the code to manipulate up to the third drop-down menu and read the entire items in the fourth drop-down menu. But the problem starts from selecting one of the items in the fourth column and calling the following items in the fifth column.

When I tried to print out the selected item, it returned the entire items in the fourth column including its title, '등급', and only the title of fifth drop-down menu, '세부등급'.

Below is the sample result that I have:

```
 등급1.8d xDrive2.0d xDrive2.3d xDrive2.5d xDrive2.8i xDrive
====level1

                          세부등급
====level2
X5 (99~13년)
```

Below is the result that I would like to have:

```
BMW - 5시리즈 - 뉴 5시리즈 (10년~현재) - 520d - F10 (10년~현재) / 럭셔리 F10 (14년~현재) / 럭셔리 플러스 F10 (15년 현재) / M 스포츠 F10 (13년) / M 에어로다이나믹 F10 (16년현재)
```

The specific part for fourth and fifth drop-down menu is:

```
520d - F10 (10년~현재) / 럭셔리 F10 (14년~현재) / 럭셔리 플러스 F10 (15년 현재) / M 스포츠 F10 (13년) / M 에어로다이나믹 F10 (16년현재)
```

Below is my code for this part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(link)
sleep(.75)
```

.....

```
#level1 means '등급'
#level2 means '세부등급'
level1_selects = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#level_no")
for level1_select in level1_selects:

if level1_select.text == '등급':
    continue
else:
    print(level1_select.text)
    select_obj = Select(level1_select)
    select_obj.select_by_value(level1_select.get_attribute('value'))
    print('====level1')
    sleep(0.75)

    level2_selects = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#level2_no")

    for level2_select in level2_selects:
        print(level2_select.text)
        select_obj = Select(level2_select)
        select_obj.select_by_value(level2_select.get_attribute('value'))
        print('====level2')
```

Comment: post the output you want.

Comment: I added that part.